# What is the most efficient way to update a Cloudant document numerous times?

Tags: cloudant

The application I am building involves a customer's ID being documented when they first use the app. As they use the app, additional data needs to be updated to this customer's record on a Cloudant DB. Therefore, this solution will require numerous updates to documents for each customer that use it.

I have looked through the following documentation, but it appears that the recommended way to solve this problem is to first GET the document with a known ID, and then ADD the document again with the new data inserted.

- https://docs.cloudant.com/tutorials/crud/index.html
- https://docs.cloudant.com/guides/eventsourcing.html

It seems that this may be inefficient due to the fact that the code would be grabbing entire documents frequently, just to make a minor change, and then adding the new document back to the DB. Given the plethora of incremental updates I plan to use in my code, I a worried about efficiency. How would you advise to address the issue of efficiency?